# Solutions to $z^5+2+e^z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I am trying to show that this equation has exactly three solutions in the half plane $\{z:\,\Re (z)<0\}$.

**Ideas**

My first thought was to use Rouche's theorem. Since it applies to closed contours, I thought of mapping the plane to something simple and bounded, like the unit disk using:
$$\phi:\;z\mapsto\frac{z+1}{z-1}$$
So I now need to show that $\phi(z)^5+e^{\phi(z)}+2$ has exactly three solutions in the unit disk. Wolfram says that: $$\phi(z)^5+2=0\iff (z+1)^5+2(z-1)^5=0$$ satisfies this, so it is tempting to prove:

- the equation above has three solutions in the unit disk
- that $|e^{z}|>|\phi(z)^5+2|$ on $|z|=1+\epsilon$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$

The problem is that I have no idea how to tackle either of these. Maybe I am taking a completely wrong route. Would be really grateful for some help.

Comment: It's fairly straightforward with the left half-plane. On the left half-plane, you have $\lvert e^z\rvert \leqslant\,?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider a semicircular contour with base on the imaginary axis and compare $e^z$ with $z^5+2$.